# What is the correct configuration to create a custom element in a Svelte 4 and vite project?

Tags: svelte, vite, custom-element

After having done the following steps

1. create Svelte project via `npm create vite@latest`

```
├── @sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte@2.4.6
├── svelte@4.2.2
└── vite@4.5.0
```

2. Change `App.svelte` to

```html
<svelte:options customElement="my-element" />

<script>
    export let character = '!'
</script>

<h1>my-element{character}</h1>

<style>
    h1 {
        color: teal;
    }
</style>
```

3. Change `main.js` to

```js
import App from './App.svelte'
export default App
```

4. Add the compiler option to `vite.config`

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import {svelte} from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [svelte({
        compilerOptions: {
            customElement: true,
        }
    })],
})
```

5. Running `npm run build`

The `dist` directory contains following files

```
dist
│   index.html
│   vite.svg
└───assets
    │   index-22b2453f.js
```

While it seems to be possible to import and use the custom element from the generated `.js` file I wonder why it's not just one `bundle.js` file as often described like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529034/svelte-custom-element-api)

What configuration is neccessary so that one `.js` file is generated with a given 'static' name without hash where the custom element can be imported from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly your question, to generate a single 'static' bundle, use `build.rollupOptions` in `vite.config.js`. You can find more informations [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885526/how-to-set-multiple-output-when-build-lib-with-vite).

Based on your example, in step #4, vite's config will look:

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import {svelte} from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      compilerOptions: {
        customElement: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: "./src/main.js",
      },
      // single
      output: {
        format: "umd",
        chunkFileNames: `[name].[hash].js`,
        entryFileNames: "my-element.umd.js", // <--
        dir: "dist",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Then you can add the file in `index.html` *(file is in `public` folder)*:

`<script type="module" src="my-element.umd.js" defer></script>`

Or import it from a Svelte component *(file is in `src` folder)*:

`import * as MyElement from './my-element.umd.js'`

And then use the custom element:

`<my-element character="⚡" />`